# .stl export has low geometry resolution

Tags: export, stl

I am having trouble getting a usable .stl file when exporting figures created in MakeHuman from Blender (and I get the same result exporting directly from MakeHuman). I have tried this with Blender 3.5 and 2.78b with the same result.

Exporting from MakeHuman in the .dae format gives a decent high resolution geometry:

[image: original]

However, exporting either from Blender or MakeHuman to .stl gives a model like this:

[image: stl]

The intended use of this is 3d printing in a small scale. I have scoured tutorials for exporting MakeHuman figures, and I cannot find any information about addressing this issue. Also, although Shapeways purports to support the .dae format, it fails when attempting to import the .dae file.

I should be grateful for any guidance on how to address or even understand this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: All models are the same "resolution" that matches the mesh native topology regardless of export format, only difference is one of them is smooth shaded the other is not.

Comment: Thank you for that - that is helpful. I had thought that applying the modifiers on export should automatically generate geometry to match any smooth shading applied?

Comment: Shading does not alter geometry in any way. That's the same geometry in both of your pictures.

Comment: Smooth shading is a visual trickery for on screen display purposes only, it has no physical bearing on the model topology. For 3D printing only actual geometry

Comment: Thank you - I have found that adding a subdivision surface modifier before exporting helps significantly.